# Does Facebook open Graph SDK v2.2 stil work?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got a client whose website uses an old version of the Facebook App SDK to display his recent Facebook posts and Photouploads as references on the site.

He only got the following files:
facebook.php
base_facebook.php

But the website hasn't shown any output from Facebook for three weeks now.
Is the older version of the SDK not supported anymore?
Is there an easy way to update the app?

Comment: The older version of the SDK is indeed unsupported. It may work in spots, but even if it does now it won't in the near future. Recent versions of the Graph API have made enormous changes in how permissions work as well as the default fields that get returned (which I suspect is your issue).

Answer (score 3):

Facebook open graph SDK v2.2 still works, and [will be deprecated on March 25, 2017](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).

Comment: There's a distinction between the Graph *API* (v2.0+ being supported) and the Graph API *PHP SDK v3* (`base_facebook.php` etc., not supported).

Comment: Yeah, the question's a bit of a mismash. I'd suspect the changes in the API broke the v3 SDK in ways it can't easily recover from.